# Proving ⊢ A∨(A→B) using Hilbert system

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, proof-theory, hilbert-calculus

I'm self-studying mathematical logic from "Introduction to Mathematical Logic" by Detlovs and Podnieks (available free [here](http://freecomputerbooks.com/Introduction-to-Mathematical-Logic.html) under CC license). Unfortunately, it doesn't come with any solutions. I'm stuck trying to prove ⊢ A∨(A→B), from Exercise 1.4.2 (i) on page 43. The text appears to be using the Hilbert-style deduction method.

**Relevant axioms (classical logic)**

> - $L_1: B \to (C \to B)$
> - $L_2: (B \to (C \to D)) \to ((B \to C) \to (B \to D))$
> - $L_6: B \to B \lor C$
> - $L_7: C \to B \lor C$
> - $L_8: (B \to D) \to ((C \to D) \to (B \lor C \to D))$
> - $L_9: (B \to C) \to ((B \to \lnot C) \to ¬B)$
> - $L_{10}: \lnot B \to (B \to C)$
> - $L_{11}: B \lor \lnot B$

**Relevant inference rules**

> - Modus Ponens

**Attempt**

1. $(A \to A \lor (A \to B)) \to ((\lnot A \to A \lor (A \to B)) \to (A \lor \lnot A \to A \lor (A \to B)))$ --- $L_8$
2. $A \to A \lor (A \to B)$ --- $L_6$
3. $A \lor \lnot A$ --- $L_{11}$
4. $(\lnot A \to A \lor (A \to B)) \to (A \lor \lnot A \to A \lor (A \to B))$ --- from (1) and (2) by MP
5. $(\lnot A \to A \lor (A \to B)) \to A \lor (A \to B)$ --- from (3) and (4) by MP
6. $(\lnot A \to (A \to A \lor (A \to B))) \to ((\lnot A \to A) \to (\lnot A \to A \lor (A \to B)))$ --- $L_2$
7. $(\lnot A \to (A \to A \lor (A \to B)))$ --- $L_{10}$
8. $(\lnot A \to A) \to (\lnot A \to A \lor (A \to B))$ --- from (6) and (7) by MP

I'm stuck at this point because $\lnot A \to A$ appears to be a contradiction. I'm also not sure whether this is the right approach. It looks alright at formula 5, but I'm not sure how to prove $\lnot A \to A \lor (A \to B)$, since it requires proving that $A \lor (A \to B)$ is always true, which is what we're trying to prove in the first place.

The text states that it can be solved using 14 formulas, 13 being the shortest yet.

Comment: The "proof strategy" is to use L11: $A \lor \lnot A$ and derive $A \lor (A \to B)$ from $A$ with L6 and from $\lnot A$ with L10. Then use L8

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I seem to have done the first three steps in my attempt (if I understood correctly); substituting B=A, C=¬A for L8 seems to yield (A→D)→((¬A→D)→D) after simplifying. The only straightforward substitution for D that I haven't tried seems to be D=(¬A→A∨(A→B)) but that leads to a double negation case with L10, which hasn't been proved yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are forced **not** tu use the Deduction Theorem.

But you can use the so-called Law of Syllogism (transitivity of $\to$).

If so, here is a sketch of a derivation:

1. $\vdash A \to (A \lor (A \to B))$ --- L6
2. $\vdash \lnot A \to (A \to B)$ --- L10
3. $\vdash (A \to B) \to (A \lor (A \to B))$ --- L7
4. $\vdash \lnot A \to (A \lor (A \to B))$ --- from 2. and 3. by Syllogism.

Now we can "cook them" together using L8:

5. $\vdash (A \to (A \lor (A \to B))) \to [(\lnot A \to (A \lor (A \to B))) \to ((A \lor \lnot A) \to (A \lor (A \to B)))]$

Now, from 5., 1. and 4. by MP twice:

> 6. $\vdash (A \lor \lnot A) \to (A \lor (A \to B))$

Finally, using L11: $\vdash A \lor \lnot A$, by MP:

> > $\vdash A \lor (A \to B)$.

Comment: Smart use of the law of syllogism! The text has proved it as a theorem, so it is straightforward to show it from (2) and (3). In total,   this gives 13 formulas (verbosely written), which the text says is the shortest proof.

Answer (score 1):

For the fun of it, I looked for smaller proofs using my own tool [pmGenerator](https://github.com/xamidi/pmGenerator) – which exhaustively generates minimal [condensed detachment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condensed_detachment) proofs.
It turned out that a minimal such proof is 13 steps long (with all its formulas being distinct), so a proof with less than 13 formulas only exists if it references the same line (i.e. uses the same formula) multiple times.

#### Proof System

It should be noted that according to page 23 in section "Omitting Parentheses" of the referenced textbook

> [image]

the **order of precedence** of operators in $\{\land,\lor,\to\}$ is $~\land,\lor~\prec~{\to}$.
For example, $L_6: B \to B \lor C$ means $B \to (B \lor C)$, which is `CpApq` in [Polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation) (a most concise prefix notation with $(\to,\lnot,\land,\lor)=($`C`,`N`,`K`,`A`$)$). All axioms from the question in Polish notation are
$L:=\{$`CpCqp`, `CCpCqrCCpqCpr`, `CpApq`, `CpAqp`, `CCpqCCrqCAprq`, `CCpqCCpNqNp`, `CNpCpq`, `ApNp`$\}$,
and there are additionally

- $L_3:$ `CKpqp` $=B\land C\to B$
- $L_4:$ `CKpqq` $=B\land C\to C$
- $L_5:$ `CpCqKpq` $=B\to(C\to B\land C)$

allowed in the book's exercise, which define the $\land$-connective.

For condensed detachment, there is the so-called `D`-rule, which takes two formulas as arguments, on which it applies [tree unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)) to form their most general unifiers of $\psi\to\varphi$ and $\psi$, respectively, then applies Modus Ponens, which results in $\varphi$.

Axioms in condensed detachment proofs are referred to by `1`,`2`,…,`9`,`a`,`b`,…,`z` in their given order.

#### Solution (automated)

A minimal `D`-proof for `ApCpq` $=A\lor(A\to B)$ under $L$ is `DDD53DD2D1478` (length 13), which translates to:

1. $A∨¬A$ $\ $---$\ \ L_{11}$
2. $¬A→(A→B)$ $\ $---$\ \ L_{10}$
3. $(A→B)→(A∨(A→B))$ $\ $---$\ \ L_7$
4. $((A→B)→(A∨(A→B)))→(¬A→((A→B)→(A∨(A→B))))$ $\ $---$\ \ L_1$
5. $¬A→((A→B)→(A∨(A→B)))$ $\ $---$\ \ \textit{MP}:3,4$
6. $(¬A→((A→B)→(A∨(A→B))))→((¬A→(A→B))→(¬A→(A∨(A→B))))$ $\ $---$\ \ L_2$
7. $(¬A→(A→B))→(¬A→(A∨(A→B)))$ $\ $---$\ \ \textit{MP}:5,6$
8. $¬A→(A∨(A→B))$ $\ $---$\ \ \textit{MP}:2,7$
9. $A→(A∨(A→B))$ $\ $---$\ \ L_6$
10. $(A→(A∨(A→B)))→((¬A→(A∨(A→B)))→((A∨¬A)→(A∨(A→B))))$ $\ $---$\ \ L_8$
11. $(¬A→(A∨(A→B)))→((A∨¬A)→(A∨(A→B)))$ $\ $---$\ \ \textit{MP}:9,10$
12. $(A∨¬A)→(A∨(A→B))$ $\ $---$\ \ \textit{MP}:8,11$
13. $A∨(A→B)$ $\ $---$\ \ \textit{MP}:1,12$

I obtained it as follows.

1. Generate all representative proofs of up to 13 steps, via
   `$ ./pmGenerator -c -n -s CpCqp,CCpCqrCCpqCpr,CpApq,CpAqp,CCpqCCrqCAprq,CCpqCCpNqNp,CNpCpq,ApNp -g 13`
2. Search for `ApCpq` in generated files via
   `$ ./pmGenerator -c -n -s CpCqp,CCpCqrCCpqCpr,CpApq,CpAqp,CCpqCCrqCAprq,CCpqCCpNqNp,CNpCpq,ApNp --search ApCpq -n`,
   resulting in output:

   ```
   Found [0] : "A0C0.1" (originally "ApCpq")
           in line 131392 - DDD53DD2D1478:A0C0.1
           of 'dProofs13.txt'.
   ```
3. Parse `DDD53DD2D1478` with formulas in infix notation (unicode, `-u`) via
   `$ ./pmGenerator -c -n -s CpCqp,CCpCqrCCpqCpr,CpApq,CpAqp,CCpqCCrqCAprq,CCpqCCpNqNp,CNpCpq,ApNp --parse DDD53DD2D1478 -u`,
   resulting in output:

   ```
    1. 0∨¬0  (8)
    2. ¬0→(0→1)  (7)
    3. (0→1)→(0∨(0→1))  (4)
    4. ((0→1)→(0∨(0→1)))→(¬0→((0→1)→(0∨(0→1))))  (1)
    5. ¬0→((0→1)→(0∨(0→1)))  (D):3,4
    6. (¬0→((0→1)→(0∨(0→1))))→((¬0→(0→1))→(¬0→(0∨(0→1))))  (2)
    7. (¬0→(0→1))→(¬0→(0∨(0→1)))  (D):5,6
    8. ¬0→(0∨(0→1))  (D):2,7
    9. 0→(0∨(0→1))  (3)
    10. (0→(0∨(0→1)))→((¬0→(0∨(0→1)))→((0∨¬0)→(0∨(0→1))))  (5)
    11. (¬0→(0∨(0→1)))→((0∨¬0)→(0∨(0→1)))  (D):9,10
    12. (0∨¬0)→(0∨(0→1))  (D):8,11
    13. 0∨(0→1)  (D):1,12
   ```
4. Use {`(1)`↦$L_1$, `(2)`↦$L_2$, `(3)`↦$L_6$, `(4)`↦$L_7$, `(5)`↦$L_8$, `(6)`↦$L_9$, `(7)`↦$L_{10}$, `(8)`↦$L_{11}$} for translation.

#### More

Using $L\cup\{L_3,L_4,L_5\}$ via `CpCqp,CCpCqrCCpqCpr,CKpqp,CKpqq,CpCqKpq,CpApq,CpAqp,CCpqCCrqCAprq,CCpqCCpNqNp,CNpCpq,ApNp` resulted in `DDD86DD2D17ab`, which by axiom translations {`(1)`↦$L_1$, …, `(9)`↦$L_9$, `(a)`↦$L_{10}$, `(b)`↦$L_{11}$} is the same proof. (I'd recommend instead of `-g 13` to use `-g 9 -g 13 -u` here, to avoid long filtering durations. I used `-g 11 -g 13 -u`, which ran over an hour.)
So there is no shortcut over $\land$-formulas.

I generated the [top 5000 list of smallest conclusions](https://pastebin.com/e9vh3rBg) provable from $\textit{MP},L_1,\dots,L_{11}$ in up to 13 steps (including minimal proofs) via
`$ ./pmGenerator -c -n -s CpCqp,CCpCqrCCpqCpr,CKpqp,CKpqq,CpCqKpq,CpApq,CpAqp,CCpqCCrqCAprq,CCpqCCpNqNp,CNpCpq,ApNp --variate 1 -s --extract -t 5000 -s`.
It includes all conclusions of symbolic lengths up to 11 (which are provable in up to 13 steps), and can be used as a resource to check for great solutions to many of the other exercises.